# Reading data from file given the width and height

Tags: c++

I have a `.dat` file that looks like this.

```
9 10 

8 10

7 10
```

I know the width and height of the file. I have a loop as follows:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < int(height); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < int(width); j++) {
    }
}
```

I need to read the numbers into a 2d vector in the same format. How would I go about writing the code inside the nested `for` loop to read the data? Assume that the 2d vector is initialized with the correct size and has default values already.

Comment: Why not simply read like `std::cin >> array[i][j];`?

Comment: @drescherjm `height` may be declared as `size_t` and `int()` may be for avoiding warnings for comparing values with different signedness.

Comment: Yes it is for that. I will try what you said @MikeCAT.

Comment: In that case, consider using `size_t` all the way through. `for (size_t i = 0; i < height; i++)` It's looks less weird, won't accidentally hide errors, and it's not like you need (or want) negative index values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::ifstream` to open the file and `operator>>` to read it inside your nested loop. The operator will handle reading the integers and skipping the whitespace for you, eg:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream file("file.dat");

for (int i = 0; i < int(height); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < int(width); ++j) {
        file >> myarray[i][j];
    }
}
```